# Sitecore - WebMethod is not being called

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sitecore, webmethod

I've seen a lot of solutions to check if a user has disabled JavaScript in server side in C# (and I mean really disabled, not if the browser doesn't support JavaScript since I already tried [EcmaScriptVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ecmascriptversion(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Here are two of the articles that I found:

- [How to detect if JavaScript is enabled from the server side in C#/.NET](http://www.broculos.net/2011/08/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-enabled.html#.VEDqFVxdXep)
- [Detect if JavaScript is enabled in ASPX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23831/Detect-if-JavaScript-is-enabled-in-ASPX)

I'm currently trying the first approach from Nuno Freitas because it seems to be the cleanest without having to play around with query string parameters, but the session variable is never setted and the SetJavascriptEnabled is never called.

I've added the ScriptManager to my aspx page like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```

And the startup script is being registered as in the article (in the OnPreRender event) but it's not being shown in the page. Btw this is a website that uses sitecore.

Any help?

Comment: We cannot write write down a solution for you. Make an effort, show us some code, explain why it doesn't work...

Comment: Your issue isn't with detecting Javascript then. It's calling web methods. You should ask a question as to why your first solution isn't working.

Comment: And are you seeing the embedded JS on the page? View source and check for `PageMethods.SetJavascriptEnabled` or similar - if that's not on the page, then it won't be called. Also check your browser console for errors around calling the methods.

Comment: Yeah I checked and PageMethods.SetJavascriptEnabled is not in the page :\

Comment: Then it sounds like you haven't wired up that part of it correctly... In your code-behind you need to add a call to `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` - make sure that's in the code and being hit. This doesn't need to be in the prerender event as per the article, it can be elsewhere.

Comment: The code is being hit and the script is being registered but it doesn't seem to be showing in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what these articles are checking is that if there is no ajax call happening from client side to server side even after writing the ajax ( $.ajax) code then javascript is disabled . It is an indirect way of checking .

Comment: Then what would be a more direct approach?

Comment: @HélderGonçalves There really isn't one :( These are your best bets, but they are indirect and subject to both latency (you won't really know until after the first page has loaded, and the JS has run) and the user could navigate away before the call is made, or it could fail to complete - none are ideal.